# Why doesn't this UIButton / IBAction refresh my page?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, ios5, uibutton

When I load my Master View it automatically loads a JSON feed with blog posts.

I have a refresh button on the top bar of my Master View. I have already connected it successfully to an `IBAction` and when clicked, I can output a string to log.

I am trying to get my view to reload the JSON feed when I click on the refresh button but that doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

**My ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UICollectionViewController {
    NSArray *posts;
}

- (void)fetchPosts;

- (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender;
@end
```

**My ViewController.m**

```
...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchPosts];
}

- (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender {

    [self fetchPosts];
}

- (void)fetchPosts
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://website.com/app/"]];

        NSError* error;

        posts = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
...
```

Comment: Does it succeed downloading the data?

Comment: Are you trying to update a UILabel? Where is  your UILabel? Is it in another view controller? Are you trying to refresh the whole view controller? View controllers doing "refresh" when you switch to another one.

Comment: You are trying to reload the view without actually reloading it? Is collectionView a UITableView that is successfully connected to interface builder referencing outlet?  Please provide more information and more of your code.

Comment: @DrummerB - not that I can see, as the page contents remain the same although there are new entries

Comment: @user1392515 - no, trying to update the entire collectionView which is displayed in a Master View -- it would be OK to relaod the MasterView

Comment: Have you try doing a NSLog on the POSTS variable right before you do the reloadData call? Try that to see if the POSTS array actually has the valid data you want.

Comment: it does because `fetchPosts` is what actually loads posts to the Master View to begin with -- I would just want to be able to do that same thing on demand by clicking on refresh button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post is not being updated as you expect as it is being captured inside of the async block. If I remember correctly, instance variables are copied once passed into a block, so changes to them aren't reflected outside of the async block unless they have the `__block` modifier.

Try this,

```
- (void)fetchPosts
{
    __block NSArray *blockPosts = posts;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://website.com/app/"]];

        NSError* error;

        blockPosts = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: harold so this code would be called for the initial load AND called when one clicks for refresh? or should it be specific for the refresh?

Comment: Yes. It's called for the initial load, AND whenever someone clicks the refresh button...IMHO

Comment: your code throws a parser error on line 3 (__block...) -- `incompatible pointer types initializing NSJSONSerialization *__strong with an expression`

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the code by changing the type of the `__block` variable to a `NSArray`; this is based on the assumption that your `posts` variable is an array. Is that correct?